# PermissionError for Azure AD integration with Flask running in container

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-active-directory

I'm integrating Azure AD to my Flask app and it's running in the container. I built it using root. But it kept saying this:

```
portal_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):

portal_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cachelib/file.py", line 229, in set

portal_1  |     os.chmod(filename, self._mode)

portal_1  | PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/src/flask_session/23ffc60799c192828aeb7335861134446'
```

What should I do to make it to have the right permission?
I'm referencing this example: https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-samples-common
But it's fine since it runs in local.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions like this and see if that works.`

```
sudo chown your_username:your_groupname filename
```